# Play video in windowed mode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

I need to develop an app that can play video in windowed mode, not in full screen mode.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple create and size the MPMoviePlayer object by code.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean in "Windowed Mode"? do you mean a UIView that appears on a UIButton and the mainview is still viewable behind it? if so  then use UIPopoverController.

Comment: I mean not in fullscreen mode. In a view for example.